# Azure Purview scan on Databrick delta-lake shows "Error: (3913) JavaException: Must have Java 8 or newer installed"

Tags: java, azure, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-purview

We have our delta-lake from which we can query data. We also connected it with Power BI to make interactive dashboards. It's in production. Now we want to use Azure Purview to avail all the data governance and data catalog things on top of this delta-lake.

We followed this official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-hive-metastore-source) and have done all the steps. As you can see from the screenshot below, we are able to connect both worlds.

[image]

Now when we start the scan, it shows an error with "Error: (3913) JavaException: Must have Java 8 or newer installed"

[image]

In the Windows VM where we are having integration runtime, we installed Java, added it to the system path, and also added JAVA_HOME as system variables as well

Here are the screenshots of that Windows VM ensuring we have Java:

`java --version`:

[image]

JAVA_HOME as System Variable:

[image]

Java directory in the Path:

[image]

We have pulled every trick we could, no luck at all. We are not sure if is there any other place where we need to install Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: (3913) JavaException: Must have Java 8 or newer install

**The message error is quite misleading**

As per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-hive-metastore-source#prerequisites),

> Ensure JDK 11 is installed on the machine where the self-hosted integration runtime is installed

Currently the Purview preview connection **only functions with JDK 11**; it is not compatible with JDK versions higher or below.

To fix this issue uninstall your current JDK installed version and install JDK 11 after installing, restart the computer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released a new documentation concerning the **Databricks connector** that avoids setting up connection to the Hive Metasore manually.

Note that it is still in *preview* and requires JDK 11 installed on the machine where the IR is installed.

You can find the newly updated documentation (as of 01/01/2023) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-databricks)

Answer (score 0):

**The above answer from Pratik Lad and halfer is true, not only for preview connectors** but for all connectors that needs java 11 jdk, such for instance Oracle connetor. In my case I followed those instructions **for Oracle connector** and it worked.
I had to unistall my previous java version (21) and re-installed the 11 one so my connector could work again, and I could perform my Oracle scan (Oct 2023).

You can also find Microsoft offcial reply (for Preview connectors) here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/633987/purview-integration-with-erwin-9-x

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).